# Can I test the tab order of a page with PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2

Tags: selenium, phpunit, tab-ordering

I want to test the tab order of my input fields on my page and I thought I could make it look something like this:

```
#get the number of inputs on the page
$input = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('div.wrapper input'));

for ($i=1; $i <= count($input); $i++) 
{ 
    #just to set focus on the field i know is the first
    if($i == 1)
    {
    $this->byId('myFirstField')->value($i);
    }   
    else
    {
    $this->keysSpecial('TAB');
    $this->get current element in focus->value($i);
    }       
}
```

Then I can either sit there and see the numbers are written in the right order or fully automate it and assert that the value is correct for every field like so:

```
$this->assertEquals($this->byId('myFirstField')->value(), 1);
$this->assertEquals($this->byId('mySecondField')->value(), 2);
```

And so on, but as you can se this code wont work, I dont know how to tell phpunit to type something in the current input field. is there a method for calling the element in focus? ie $this->inFocus()->value($i); ?

and btw I can't use $input[$i-1]->value($i); because the tab order and the index of the fields will not be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic example using java, should be able to use a simulair solution in php I guess.

```
TabOrderElements.class{
public WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
public WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
public WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
public WebElement element4 = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
public WebElement element5 = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
}

public void validateTabOrder(){
    TabOrderElements tabOrderElements = new TabOrderElements();

    public  String[] tabOrder = {
      "element1",
      "element2",
      "element3",
      "element4",
      "element5"
    };

    for (String currentField: tabOrder ){    
        WebElement expected = (WebElement)elements.getClass().getField(currentField).get(tabOrderElements );
        WebElement actual = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        String assertMessage    = "Incorrect tab order when trying to tab to: "+fieldName;
        Assert.assertEquals(assertMessage, expected, actual);
        driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the command would be in PHP, however in Python, you can just use something like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("id of the field")
element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB, "Text you want to populate the field with")
```

There should be a PHP equivalent, also this page: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#building-test-cases has information you may need as well.